# flutter get widget width and height inside init state

Tags: flutter

I have a widget with layout builder:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {

      return Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(100,20),
          child: Container(
                 width: 50,
                 height: 50
                 );
    },
  );
}
```

I want to get the BoxConstraint of the layout builder inside initState:

```
double height;
double width;

void initState() {
  super.initState();

  // get constraint
  height = constraint.maxHeight;
  width = constraint.maxWidth;
 
}
```

How can I achieve such a thing?

Comment: what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have varies kinds of tween animations. each animation has different kind of end and start variables that rely on the width and height. I need to access the width and height before constructing the build method

Comment: So why you need to access in the init method? You can use setstate method to update the values of your variables and then use later

Comment: Because this page has different configurations. and each time a user enters the page , he gets one random configuration that start animating when opening the page.
So I need to start animating from the init state, but to animate I need the width and height

Comment: So better do one thing define a random or your choice of width or height in the init method and then use those values for twewn